# Infinite loop during Facebook Authorization

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this simple code:

```
// index.php
require_once("/fb/facebook.php");
require_once("/config/config.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $config['appId'],
    'secret' => $config['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user === 0) {      

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/join.php'      
    ));

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");    
    exit;

}
else {      
    var_dump($facebook->api("/me"));    
}
```

and the join.php code is:

```
//join.php
require_once("/fb/facebook.php");
require_once("/config/config.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $config['appId'],
    'secret' => $config['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
));

if (isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {    
    echo("<script>top.location.href='". $config['errors']['auth'] . "'</script>");
    exit;
}

echo("<script>top.location.href='". $config['url'] . "'</script>");
```

the problem is that when i go to: http://apps.facebook.com/myappsample (and I'm NOT logged on facebook) the application show the auth dialog (correctly) but after this step it does an infinite loop from **index.php** to **join.php**.

As you can see when I check if there are any errors in join.php i do a redirect to index.php (the home page of the application) BUT in the index.php I still get `$user === 0` so it redirects another time to join.php....etc etc etc (infinite loop).

How can I fix this kind of problem?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** 
I use **join.php** as callback (redirect_uri) for the login page. THe purpose of this page is to save inside a database the informations about the user, so join.php will do it and then redirect to index.php to let user use the application. Wrong?

Comment: why do you want the user to go to join.php? fb will take unauthorized  user to login page and then redirect back to your app, so it should be fine, isn't it ?

Comment: what is the purpose of join.php? what is `$config['url]` and `$config['errors']['auth']?` It seems it is supposed to redirect if there is a success.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla please see the EDIT on the question

Comment: @Yan please see the EDIT above. $config['url] is the canvas (https://www.example.com/) and then ['errors']['auth'] is a custom page that I show when there was an error during the authentication. As you can see i check if the 'error' paramenter is set, if it is i show that page to inform that user denied the authorization.

Comment: You can simply save the user data into the database in the `else` condition in `index.php`. There is no need for a redirect to complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$facebook->getUser()` in order to actually process the callback data to find the access token in `join.php`.